# MSDeploy Parameter

Tags: msdeploy

I am trying to pass application pool password as a command line argument to msdeploy.exe. Also, I am passing setParameter file as another command line agrument. The overall command line looks like this

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=D:\package.zip,encryptPassword="password" dest:auto,computername=mycompuetrname -setParam:name="AppPoolPassword",value="mypassword" -setParamFile="D:\Test.setParameters.xml"
```

Other things to be noted, Test.setParameters.xml file does NOT have AppPoolPassword param, because I want to pass that as command line as mentioned above.

When I execute the above command, I get an error which says "ApplicationPoolPassword cannot be null". If I do not specify the parameters.xml file but just specify AppPoolIdentity and AppPoolPassword on the command line the command is successful and creates the necessary web site structure.

My question is does setParamFile overrides the -setParam command line paramters? I did google search but did not find anything which confirms that. Anyone who has experienced this, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding setParamFile overriding setParam, you've got it backwards.  The setParam parameter takes precedence over the setParamFile.

Regarding the error, it looks like your parameter names are off.  The error references parameter name "ApplicationPoolPassword".  Your command is using the parameter name "AppPoolPassword".  Try changing the command to use the name "ApplicationPoolPassword".